# forEach() with forOf() with async/await?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, foreach, callback

I was making this program on asynchronously typer? Where every line typed asynchronously?
This is my html

```
<h1 data-type data-type-min="100" data-type-max="300">How are you</h1>
 <h2 data-type data-type-min="20" data-type-max="80">What are you doing?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </h2>
  <h3 data-type>whats up?</h3>
```

Here is my JS
This is my callback for aync typing-

```
async function draw(el) {
  const text = el.textContent;
  let soFar = '';
  for (const letter of text) {
    soFar += letter;
    el.textContent = soFar;
    await wait(1000);
  }
}
```

here I attach this callback with a forEach method.

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-type]').forEach(draw);
```

I can't understand that why those 3 lines are not start typing concurrently. First and third line started typing first and then after some time second line start typing. How this callback is working?

Comment: You don't have await after for statement, for await(const letter of text) {
    soFar += letter;
    el.textContent = soFar;
    await wait(1000);
  }

Comment: Now it takes some time to start the whole output.

Comment: Your current code works as expected. May be you are experiencing the problem, because there might be other events running in your application, which some what delays the `wait` setTimeout calls. When you use setTimeout, it does not call the given function on the exact milliseconds provided. The only guarantee is that it will not call the callback before the given milliseconds. Once the milliseconds are passed, the callback will be moved to some queue, where it will wait, if there are some other DOM processing is happening or if there are many other callbacks.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please provide the exact code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @EfrosIonelu No, you should **not** use `for await` here. There's no async generator, just a loop over a string.

Comment: What are `data-type-min` and  `data-type-max`? Are they used in your actual code?